# Showing part of an image?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to show half an image, the top part to be specific.

I am running into some issues when trying to do this.

When trying to clip the image it dissappears? I'm using Bulma CSSframework but it seems to not let me show half of the image? It works fine outside Bulma.

I've tried answers on other questions, they just result in the image disappearing.

```
<article class="media">
    <figure class="media-left">
        <p class="image"><img style="margin-top:-20px;position:absolute;clip:rect(0,73px,63px,0);" src="https://habboon.pw/habbo-imaging/avatarimage/figure?figure={{ auth::user()->look }}&gesture=sml&size=m"></p>
    </figure>
    <div class="media-content">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052180/show-part-of-an-image-in-media

Comment: What's the point in linking a dead question?

Comment: Did you try pure CSS? it's pretty easy to do with it

Answer (score 0):

> The clip CSS property defines what portion of an element is visible.
>   The clip property applies **only to absolutely positioned elements**, that
>   is elements with position:absolute or position:fixed.

Please note that this feature is **Deprecated** according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
>   Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the
>   compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision.
>   Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

Instead, you can use `clip-path`

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that defines what part of an element should be displayed. More specifically, those portions that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden.

```
// clip-path: polygon(point1 [x,y], point2[x,y], point3[x,y],....pointN[x,y]);
// this creates a rect with full width and only half height
clip-path:  polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%,0 50%);
```

Note that this method will "cut out" the bottom half of your image, there is another approach that allows you to keep the full image and put an overlay over the bottom half if that suits your situation

---

**Update**

> clip (and the more recent clip-path) merely defines a path for clipping, it doesn't change the width/height of the element being clipped.

Though you can achieve your target by some workaround like below

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 300px;
    
    /*Set the height = 1/2 of your image height*/
    height: 150px;
    
    /*clip-path is not needed now*/
    /*clip-path:  polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%,0 50%);*/
    
    /*Instead you can use background-image with size set to cover*/
    background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300/100");
    background-size: cover;


  

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: This still takes up the space the full image would take, which isn't what I want.

Comment: @burido Are you trying to clip it and leave the bottom half blank?

Comment: not blank, just only take up space for the part that's shown of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The `img` is a child of `p.image`. The class `.image` has the rule `position: relative`.

I'm not sure why, but this is causing an issue with the `img` displaying. You can either remove `.image` from the container, or add a custom class which overrules `position: relative`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyLtfu11/11/)

```css
.clip-image {
  position: static !important;
}

img {
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 73px, 63px, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<article class="media">
    <figure class="media-left">
        <p class="image clip-image"><img src="https://unsplash.it/300"></p>
    </figure>
    <div class="media-content">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```